# overflow:visible for certain items

Tags: html, css, overflow, z-index

I have the following problem: I'm trying to create rich-text editor based on StacksEditor but when the dropdown is longer that the editor view, it's not shown entirely like here on the screen

[image]

I can delete `overflow-scroll` class from the second top div on the screen and then the dropdown is shown properly:

[image]

But of course the text is now also not scrolling and overflow the editor:
[image]

How can I fix that? Where should I put `position:relative` and where `position:aboslute` and what `z-index` values?

Comment: Please see [ask]. We can't debug images. Put a simplified example in a demo using the editor.